# While copy the entities which contains groups and paste that entities in same drawing original entites group name changed like *A3 etc

Tags: c#, autocad

Hi Friends,
              I struggle with following issues. My doubt is while i copy the entities which contains group and paste it in same drawing. Now original entities group names are changed to *A3 or some anonymous name.I am using autocad 2007.I unable to find the original entities group name. Is there any possibilities to do this kind of works.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

if you copy a set of objects in AutoCAD and paste them in the same DWG, it will have to rename do to the fact that you can't have multiple objects or groups with the same name. Otherwise how would the application be able to differentiate between them?